# js-data: What is the difference between "none" and "inject" for DS "reapAction" configuration option?

Tags: javascript, jsdata, js-data-angular

I have the following definitions:

- `"none"` - do nothing
- `"inject"` - re-inject the items back into the data store

The above definition is taken from the official documentation. I don't understand what's the point of *re-injecting items back into the DS*? To a consumer of the resource, how does it differ from *doing nothing*?

At first impression, I thought re-injecting would update the *lastModified* timestamp but it doesn't, as verified by running a sample app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but the documentation was misleading, and has now been fixed.

What the `reap` method's `inject` option actually does is reset expired items' expiry timeout to the value of the `maxAge` option, whereas the `none` option does not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, jdobry. Now that I see the difference between how the two `reapAction` options work, it's still unclear to me in what scenarios I would choose one over the other. To a consumer of a DS, regardless which option is in use,  expired items are always left untouched in the DS.

Btw, **js-data** is a great data modelling framework. Although I have only been using it for a few days, I am already in love with it. Great work. Thank you.

Comment: Yep! I myself have never used those two particular options. I prefer to manually manage when and what cached data needs to be flushed.